# MySQL query that matches two fields and has another field in common

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table like this:

```
id |  f1 | f2
 1 |  a  | hi
 2 |  a  | sup
 3 |  b  | hi
```

I need a query that grabs the rows where f2 = hi OR f2 = sup, but only if f1 has the same value in both rows. So my query would grab id 1 and id 2, but NOT 3

So basically this -

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`f2` = 'hi' OR `f2` = 'sup') AND 'f1-is-the-same'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
    FROM YourTable t1
        INNER JOIN YourTable t2
            ON t1.f1 = t2.f1
    WHERE t1.f2 = 'hi'
        AND t2.f2 = 'sup'
```

Comment: I think you should check t1.id <> t2.id  on you join (as I did) otherwise it will join rows with the same id.

Comment: @kibbee: Look at the WHERE clause. Those two rows also need to have two different values for `f2`, so no danger of matching the same row here.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.  Thought that "AND" looked a little strange.  Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` as t1 
WHERE (`f2` = 'hi' OR `f2` = 'sup') 
  AND f1 in (select f1 from `table` where id <> t1.id)
```

Comment: I ended up having to add another field:
WHERE ((`f2` = 'hi' AND `newfield` = 'blah') OR (`f2` = 'sup')) which this worked better for

Answer (score 0):

A query like this should do the trick

```
SELECT T1.id,T1.F1,T2.F2
FROM Table as T1
INNER JOIN Table as T2 
ON T1.F1=T2.F1 AND T1.ID <> T2.ID
WHERE T1.F2= 'hi' or T1.F1='sup'
```