# Get rows matching all items from an array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can do it with a loop or an alternate solution, but this would mean time consuming (on page loading).... So I would like to know if there is a 'one query' solution.

I have a table containing 4 columns:

```
id   class    day    hour
 1   9b3      1      3      
 2   9b4      1      3
 3   9b5      1      3
 4   9b3      1      5
 5   9b4      2      6
 6   9b5      2      6
 7   9b4      4      7
 8   9b3      3      6
 9   9b4      3      6
 10  9b5      3      6
```

What I need is to recover the day and hour matching all three classes 9b3, 9b4, 9b5 at the same day and hour.

In the example above, the result should be:

```
day   hour
1      3
3      6
```

Comment: Here's a similar question that has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797743/mysql-query-that-matches-two-fields-and-has-another-field-in-common

Comment: The link you point me to is working.... As long that you need to match one of the element in the array. The thing I want is to find the days and hours where all elements has the same value, not "at least one element of the array". Hope you will understand my poor English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT day,hour
FROM yourTableName
WHERE class IN ('9b3','9b4','9b5')
GROUP BY day,hour
HAVING COUNT(class) = 3;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26198/3)</kbd>

Comment: Please explain your snippet with the intent of educating future readers.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT day,hour FROM table
WHERE class IN('9b3','9b4','9b5') GROUP BY day HAVING COUNT(class)=3;
```

Where filters rows ,Having filters groups.

Comment: Using only GROUP BY day does not work. But using GROUP BY day, hour is working!

Comment: Please include an educational explanation in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

also that works...

```
SELECT day,hour
FROM Table1
WHERE (class = '9b3' or class =  '9b4' or class = '9b5')
GROUP BY day,hour
HAVING COUNT(class) = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved simple by using SQL statement syntax depending on the action that you want to perform. Picking the raw data can be done like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable
   WHERE day='1' and hour='3'
```